# MVC routes me to non-existent path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the default route.  I have setup a method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult HtmlButton2(FormCollection collection)
{
    //implementation
    return View("Index");
}
```

Which when it runs it returns me to

```
http://serverName/{controller}/HtmlButton2
```

The `POST` originates from `http://serverName/` (visible in the URL..the actual page is `http://serverName/Index`).

Ideally, I would like to be routed back to

> http://serverName

I believe the problem is in my

```
return View("Index");
```

The Index page is visible, but the problem is that when I refresh the page, the aforementioned `HtmlButton2()` method keeps handling the calls...which I do not want.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `return RedirectToAction("Index");` When you are returning `View("Index")` you are telling MVC to render the view, not change the URL.

Comment: This does appear to solve the problem.  Only, I have a ViewBag.Message which is somehow lost now.  Does ViewBag not persist with RedirectToAction?